# how to access previous index with array list?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

**I Have Code like below**

```
List<Transaction> ts = transaksiRepo.findAll();
 for (Transaction data5 : ts) {
        if (data5.getStatus().equals("NOT PAID OFF")) {
            log.info("Testing");
        }
 }
```

*I want to get previous data index to condition if else on code in array list*

**Like this**

```
List<Transaction> ts = transaksiRepo.findAll();
 for (Transaction data5 : ts) {
        if (data5.getStatus().equals("NOT PAID OFF") && previous index.getStatus.equals("NOT PAID OFF")) {
            log.info("Testing getStatementDate");
        }
 }
```

**How do I resolve this?**

Answer (score 3):

You can use simple `for loop` and achieve this easily.

I have started index starting from `1` as we will be comparing previous index i.e. `0`th element.

Modify the `logic` as per your needs.

```
List<Transaction> ts = transaksiRepo.findAll();
for (int i=1;i<ts.size();i++) {
    if (ts.get(i).getStatus().equals("NOT PAID OFF") && ts.get(i-1).getStatus.equals("NOT PAID OFF")) {
        log.info("Testing getStatementDate");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use ShubhWIP's answer, but if you absolutely prefer the enhanced for loop, you can still use it:

```
List<Transaction> ts = transaksiRepo.findAll();
Transaction prevTs = null;
for (Transaction data5 : ts) {
    if (data5.getStatus().equals("NOT PAID OFF") && prevTs != null && prevTs.getStatus.equals("NOT PAID OFF")) {
        log.info("Testing getStatementDate");
    }
    prevTs = ts;
}
```